# npm WARN babel-loader@6.2.8 requires a peer of babel-core@^6.0.0 but none was installed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to install [***Babel***](https://github.com/babel/babel) and two other plugins to use with ***Webpack*** and ***Reactjs***.

I used this command :

```
npm i babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react -S
```

which gives me warning messages :

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY babel-core@^6.0.0
```

and this one :

```
npm WARN babel-loader@6.2.8 requires a peer of babel-core@^6.0.0 but none was installed.
```

And an error message :

```
ERROR in Cannot find module 'babel-core'
```

How can I fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just had the same problem. You can check how to install using babel's web site. Go to http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/ and, in this case, select the build system Webpack.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason behind this is that [npm](https://npmjs.com) deprecated [auto-installing of peerDependencies](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6565) since npm@3, so required peer dependencies like babel-core and webpack must be listed explicitly in your `package.json`.

All that you need to do is to install babel-core.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I will do that.

Comment: @LukeCarelsen Can you be more specific? What's the error you're getting? [Here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#installation) you can see exactly all the peer dependencies required by `babel-loader`.

Comment: @CosminAbabei My bad, i managed to come right yesterday and forgot to update this comment. Thanks for getting back to me

Comment: `npm install babel-core`

Answer (score 6):

Just added this line:

```
"babel-core": "^6.0.0",
```

to my package.json file (dependency), tried the same command again and the warning message vanished.

EDIT:
To get rid of this error:

```
ERROR in Cannot find module 'babel-core'
```

I installed babel-core along with the other plugins using this command:

```
npm i babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react -S
```

Comment: Thanks.. save my time